# How to access a JSON element returning from a Parse.com query?

Tags: javascript, json, parse-platform

I´m having problems when trying to access a JSON element which I get in response from a query into a Parse.com Class.

I´ve read the questions/answers about similar topics and still can´t solved it.

This is my query:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("todoenuno", function(request, response) {

    var User = Parse.Object.extend("_User");
    var query = new Parse.Query(User);
    query.equalTo("TipoUsuario", {"__type": "Pointer", "className": "Tipo_de_Usuario", "objectId": "UgTuNHEQEZ"}); 
    query.find({
        success: function(results) {
            response.success(results[0]);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
            response.error('Request failed with response code ' + error.status);
        }
    });
});
```

So, when I call the function `todoenuno(`) I get this:

```
{
  "result": {
    "Apellido": "Galli",
    "Nombre": "Gabriel",
    "NombreSede_FK": {
      "__type": "Pointer",
      "className": "Sedes",
      "objectId": "JNMeQHySaD"
    },
    "Sexo": "M",
    "TipoUsuario": {
      "__type": "Pointer",
      "className": "Tipo_de_Usuario",
      "objectId": "UgTuNHEQEZ"
    },
    "TipoUsuario_FK": {
      "__type": "Pointer",
      "className": "Tipo_de_Usuario",
      "objectId": "Aprendiz"
    },
    "Turno_FK": {
      "__type": "Pointer",
      "className": "Turnos",
      "objectId": "3lgY2zVyLD"
    },
    "__type": "Object",
    "className": "_User",
    "createdAt": "2015-05-23T15:07:17.202Z",
    "email": "gabriel@gmail.com",
    "objectId": "PqhqC7HqIj",
    "updatedAt": "2015-05-30T14:48:28.287Z",
    "username": "GabrielGalli"
  }
}
```

The results from the query are OK but I need to access individual elements.

For example, I would like to get the value "Galli".

I tried using things like:

```
response.success(results[0].Apellido); //or response.success(results[0]["Apellido"];
```

And I got an empty JSON.

If I try:

```
response.success(results.result.Apellido);
```

I get **"Can´t read "Apellido" from undefined..."**

I´m new in programming so please excuse me if this is a very stupid question but I can´t find the solution after spending so much time looking for the answers in similar topics.

Thanks in advance and sorry for my English!

Comment: I'm not familiar with parse.com, but `results.result.Apellido` looks correct to me based on what you've stated. So perhaps what you've stated isn't entirely correct; are you sure you actually have a JavaScript object or is `results` actually a string of JSON that needs to be parsed still?

Comment: What I stated is what I get after I called the function with POSTMAN I think that the trick is in the type of array/object/"thing" that came back in the response.success. I try to JSON.parse(results); but still can´t access after. @AnthonyGrist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that JSON is results[0] then you would use this to get "Galli":

```
results[0].result.Apellido
```

**EDIT:** Looks like in the [documentation](https://www.parse.com/docs/js/guide#queries), results[0] is a Parse.Object, so you would use the get() method:

```
results[0].get('Apellido')
```

Comment: Doing that I get {"code":141,"error":"TypeError: Cannot read property 'Apellido' of undefined\n    @ben

Comment: YES! Thanks man, you rock! And what about the nested elements like the "objectId" inside "NombreSede_FK"? @Ben

Comment: Try results[0].get('NombreSede_FK').objectId **or** use get() all the way through: results[0].get('NombreSede_FK').get('objectId') **or** it looks like there is a shorthand for objectId: results[0].get('NombreSede_FK').id. I will update my answer to reflect this

Comment: I tried all of that possibilities but I got empty results. When I solve this, I will update the main post.

Comment: Since "NombreSede_FK" is a pointer to another Class, I will have to include it first. Then, the sinxtax above will do the job. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use this to get the desired result:

```
function getAttributeByIndex(obj, index){
  var i = 0;
  for (var attr in obj){
    if (index === i){
      return obj[attr];
    }
    i++;
  }
  return null;
}
    console.log(getAttributeByIndex(response, 0));
```

Comment: Where does the `getAttributeByIndex` function come from? Also, since they're not working with an array, why do you expect this to work?